# I want to create lookup data using apache_beam.utils.shared module but it gives error TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'list' object

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

`

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.utils import shared
from log_elements import LogElements

class GetNthStringFn(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self, shared_handle):
    self._shared_handle = shared_handle

  def process(self, element):
    def initialize_list():
      # Build the giant initial list.
      return [str(i) for i in range(1000000)]

    giant_list = self._shared_handle.acquire(initialize_list)
    yield giant_list[element]

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
  shared_handle = shared.Shared()

  (p | beam.Create([2, 4, 6, 8])

     | beam.ParDo(GetNthStringFn(shared_handle))

     | LogElements())
```

`

I tried example given in apache beam documentation.
Link https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.24.0/apache_beam.utils.shared.html

but got below error

```
File "/opt/playground/backend/executable_files/4a6babb9-9ea4-4a70-881d-559057592090/4a6babb9-9ea4-4a70-881d-559057592090.py", line 39, in process
    giant_list = self._shared_handle.acquire(initialize_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/shared.py", line 312, in acquire
    return _shared_map.acquire(self._key, constructor_fn, tag)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/shared.py", line 253, in acquire
    result = control_block.acquire(constructor_fn, tag)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/shared.py", line 149, in acquire
    self._ref = weakref.ref(result)
TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'list' object [while running 'ParDo(GetNthStringFn)']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't reference the good link and version, the `Beam` version `2.24.0` is too old.

Check with this code and this [link](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.42.0/apache_beam.utils.shared.html) :

```py
# Several built-in types such as list and dict do not directly support weak
# references but can add support through subclassing:
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html
class WeakRefList(list):
  pass

class GetNthStringFn(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self):
    self._shared_handle = shared.Shared()

  def setup(self):
    # setup is a good place to initialize transient in-memory resources.
    def initialize_list():
      # Build the giant initial list.
      return WeakRefList([str(i) for i in range(1000000)])

    self._giant_list = self._shared_handle.acquire(initialize_list)

  def process(self, element):
    yield self._giant_list[element]

p = beam.Pipeline()
(p | beam.Create([2, 4, 6, 8])
   | beam.ParDo(GetNthStringFn()))
```

To be able to execute this code, you need to install the `Beam` `2.42.0` version. You can install it with [pip](https://pypi.org/project/apache-beam/2.42.0/) in your virtual env.